# Dotnet for Linux: Console Input Cursor Navigation

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ubuntu, .net-core

When using console input in .NET on Ubuntu (e.g. `Console.ReadLine()`), I am unable to use the arrow keys, home/end keys, etc to move the input cursor. Is there some way to enable this? It's getting rather irritating not being able to go back and correct typos without deleting everything in-between. Bonus points if the up/down-arrows can be used for input history.

Comment: I don't have a Ubuntu machine to check on at the moment, but I believe `CTRL+A` and `CTRL+E` move the cursor to the start/end of the line. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the NuGet package `ReadLine`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReadLine/2.0.0